# Android How Get Responce from Web Server from the following URL With Authentication UserName and Password

Tags: php, android, web-services, security, authentication

How I Can get this in Android "Native"

Like the Following URL In Browser i Attach the Images for Better Under Standing

How we Can get the Get the Responce from the following URL in Android with UserName and Password Authentication

http://eboundservices.com/hash/hash_app.php?code=com.eboundservices.pakistantv

User Name: hashapp

PassWord:  PlayFair00

After click On Login Show a string in Browser Like this.

c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTAvMTEvMjAxNCAyOjU2OjU3IFBNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9R3liN29aK2xQZW94UnhXbjZCaTVxZz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0yJmlkPTE=

I want to get this in Android "Native"

[image: Authentication Required "User Name" and "Password"]

[image: Responce whne Correct "User Name" and "Password"]

[image: In Case of Wrong "User Name" or "Password"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add permissions
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```
>
> Layout
>
> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView_token"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="15dp"
>      android:textSize="22sp"
>     android:text="@string/token" />
> ```
>
> Java Classes
>
> InternetConnection Class
>
> ```
> package com.rashid.token;
> ```
>
> import android.content.Context; import
>   android.net.ConnectivityManager; import android.net.NetworkInfo;
>   import android.view.Gravity; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> public class InternetConnection {     public Context context;
>
> public InternetConnection(Context context) {        this.context =
>   context;  }
>
> public boolean hasConnection() {
>
> ```
>   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
>           .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>
>   NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
>           .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);         if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {             return true;        }
>
>   NetworkInfo mobNetWork = cm
>           .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);       if (mobNetWork != null && mobNetWork.isConnected()) {           return true;        }
>
>   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();      if
> ```
>
> (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {          return
>   true;         }
>
> ```
>   return false;   }
> ```
>
> public void showToast(Context contex) {         Toast toast =
>   Toast.makeText(contex,
>                 "Internet Connection Not Available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);       toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);         toast.show();   }
>
> }
>
> TokenListener Class
>
> ```
> package com.rashid.token;
> ```
>
> public interface TokenListener {
>
> public void onTaskCompleteString(int obj, String str);
>
> }
>
> WebServiceToken Class
>
> ```
> package com.rashid.token;
> ```
>
> import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; import
>   org.apache.http.HttpResponse; import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
>   import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials; import
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; import
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; import
>   org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
>
> import android.app.ProgressDialog; import android.content.Context;
>   import android.os.AsyncTask;
>
> public class WebServiceToken extends AsyncTask {
>
> private ProgressDialog pdia;
>
> private Context context;    TokenListener tokenInterface;
>
> String Username = "hashapp";    String Password = "PlayFair00";     String
>   url =
>   "http://eboundservices.com/hash/hash_app.php?code=com.eboundservices.pakistantv";
>
> public WebServiceToken(Context context) {       // TODO Auto-generated
>   constructor stub
>
> ```
>   tokenInterface = (TokenListener) context;       this.context = context;
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Override   protected void onPreExecute() {         super.onPreExecute();
>
> ```
>   pdia = new ProgressDialog(context);         pdia.setCancelable(false);
>   pdia.setMessage("Please wait...");      pdia.show();
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Override   protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
>
> ```
>   String xml = null;      try {
>
>       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();             HttpPost
> ```
>
> httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
>             httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
>                     new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Username, Password));
>
> ```
>       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
>       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();           xml =
> ```
>
> EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);         } catch (Exception e) {
>
> ```
>       e.printStackTrace();        }
>
>   return xml;
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Override   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         super.onPostExecute(result);
>
> ```
>   pdia.dismiss();
>
>   if (result != null) {
>
>       tokenInterface.onTaskCompleteString(1, result);
>
>   } else {            tokenInterface.onTaskCompleteString(2, "");         }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> MainActivity Class
>
> ```
> package com.rashid.token;
> ```
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.view.Menu; import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TokenListener {
>
> private TextView tokenTextView;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     initializeUI();
>
>     callWebService();
> }
>
> /**
>  * This Method is Used to Initialize UI Components
>  */
> private void initializeUI() {         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>     tokenTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_token);  }
>
> /**
>  * Here I call Web Servive
>  */
> private void callWebService() {       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>     try {
>        //==========> call Web Service here <==========//
>
>           InternetConnection connection;
>           connection = new InternetConnection(MainActivity.this);
>           if (connection.hasConnection()) {
>               new WebServiceToken(MainActivity.this).execute();
>           } else {
>
>               connection.showToast(MainActivity.this);
>           }
>            //==========> End service<==========//         } catch (Exception e) {
>       // TODO: handle exception
>       e.printStackTrace();        }
>
>       }
> ```
>
> /**      * Here Responce Token Set to the TextView   */     @Override
>     public void onTaskCompleteString(int obj, String str) {         // TODO
>   Auto-generated method stub
>                 tokenTextView.setText(str);     }
>        }

Answer (score 1):

You are going to use http authentication to supply user name/password to the website first of all, the cryptic string shown in screen shot is the authentication token.
Once you are authenticated, you will send user name/password/auth. token in http headers to the server.
Please note that I keep string constants in a separate fine called K, names of those constants are pretty descriptive and you will need to bring in suitable values.

private boolean authenticate(){

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(K.URL_AUTHENTICATE);
String strAuthToken = "";
// Request parameters and other properties.

try{
    httpPost.setHeader(K.HEAD_AUTHORIZATION, K.STR_BASIC);
    httpPost.setHeader(K.HEAD_USERNAME, K.STR_NAEEM);
    httpPost.setHeader(K.HEAD_PASS, K.STR_SECRET);          
}catch(Exception exc){
    exc.printStackTrace();
    return (mbIsAuthenticated = false);
}

/*
 * Making HTTP Request
 */
try {
    Log.i(K.LOGSERV, "Sending auth. request to server.");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

    if (respEntity != null) {
        String content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
        Log.d(K.LOGSERV, content);

        JSONObject jobject = null;
        JSONArray jfinalData = null;
        JSONObject jrow = null;

        jobject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(content).nextValue();
        strAuthToken = jobject.getString("auth_token");

        if(strAuthToken.length() > 0){
            Shared.getInstance().getDB(this).updateGeneralSetting(BSRDB.SETTING_AUTH_TOKEN, strAuthToken);
            mbIsAuthenticated = true;
        }               
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
    mbIsAuthenticated = false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
    mbIsAuthenticated = false;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    mbIsAuthenticated = false;
}
return mbIsAuthenticated;
```

}

The code above was used with a web-service hosted on Amazon S2 cloud.